# The approach of labelling a collection of documents using a shared topic

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, natural-language

I have a collection of documents, and know they may share a single topic. Is there a way to identify this topic? I know LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) is an approach. But LDA result is to associate each document with a set of topics. However, I am more interested to find a common topic that can be used to label this collection.